# Is it possible to ignore missing role in Ansible?

Tags: vagrant, ansible, ansible-role

I'm using Vagrant+Ansible on a project. I want to make it optional for the user to provide a role called "workspace" which will be included in the provisioning. This allows the user to set his own preferred prompt, editor etc.

If a role that doesn't exist is specified in a playbook, the whole thing crashes with

> ERROR! The role 'workspace' was not found ...

I would like it to simply ignore it and move on. I tried adding `failed_when: false`, but unsurprisingly it had no effect. It is possible to formulate a `when: ...` condition that can check if the role exists? Or is there another way to solve this nicely?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at ansible documentation for [Conditionals](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_conditionals.html), I don't think it's directly possible to check whether a role exists.

Workarounding this via check if a directory for the role exists would be a little tricky, as there are multiple places where ansible searches for roles and some are based on current platform, environment or configuration.

That said, I tried a bit different approach which seems to work: Instead of insisting on a predefined role name, one can ask for a role name via ansible variable. Then you can include this role like this:

```
- name: Minimal playbook example
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  vars:
    role_name: ""
  roles:
    - role: "{{ role_name }}"
      when: role_name != ""
```

When user doesn't provide it's own role name, this role is not included. Also note that for this to work, you need to specify a default value for a role name variable, otherwise the ansible would fail on undefined variable (adding `is defined` check into when clause doesn't help).